# How can I update my SQL database on selectbox option change (php)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a selectbox which should update my SQL database by option change. Because in this case I do not have a normal submit input field, `if(isset($_GET['submit']))`is not working, but I do not know how to write the statement in the right way:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE colors set status = ? WHERE id = '$id'";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($status));
        Database::disconnect();
}
?>      

                    <form action="index.php" method="get">
                        <select name="status" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                        <option value="red">red</option>
                        <option value="blue">blue</option>
                    </select>
<?php echo "<input id='id' type='hidden' value='"$id"'>";?>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not just do the check on another value??

Comment: @Abdulla and why does he have to do it with Ajax?

Comment: @Abdulla: Do you mean doing it like this? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as

```
if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this line

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
```

with

```
if(array_key_exists('status',$_GET) && $_GET['status']!=""){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$id = "YourID";
if(!empty($_GET["status"])){
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != ""){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        //continue...
    }else{
        //display error (ID has not been set.)
    }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <select name="status" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
    </select>
    <?php echo "<input name='id' id='id' type='hidden' value='$id'>";?>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `isset()` with `!empty()` as `empty()` checks if it's set and have a value, rendering your first `isset()` useless. [php.net/empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: @Epodax ,Thank you. It was a good tip. The answer were edited.